# How to add link to xsl view in XML via Spring Boot Rest?

Tags: xml, spring-boot, xslt

RestController output the xml, How I can add link to my xsl view on xml file? May be exist post processors in spring boot ?

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="yourxsl.xsl"?>
```